# Segmentation fault when not deleting files C++

Tags: c++, shell, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, system

I have a program written in C++ that uses a lot the "system" function to run things like i would run in Shell (using Ubuntu 12.04 32 bits).

The things done in the "system" function generate several files that will be processed. In a second part of the program i process those files.

When the program ends, it doesn't delete those files that was generated by the "system" functions.

When i run the program for the first time it runs fine, when i run in a second time it gives me Segmentation fault (core dumped) in a given loop of the second part. It does less iterations each time i try to run. For example : **First run** = ran fine. **Second run** = Segmentation fault(core dumped) in iteration 200. **Third run** = Segmentation fault(core dumped) in iteration 199. And goes on...

I resolved the problem deleting all files it had generated by "system" function in the end of each "run" of the program.

My question is...**any one has any clue about why was it happening**?

**EDIT***

Below is a few pseudocode to exemplify.....unfortunately i cant put the entire code, its like 600 lines.

```
int main(void){

// Part 1 of the program.....severam "system" producing files
system("bash produceSeveralFiles.sh");

// Part 2 of the program......process files produced in part 1
processFiles();

// My Solution that i dont know why solves it
system("rm AllFiles");

return 0;
}
```

**EDIT***

Way i checked that it goes until the loop...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 300 ; i++){
  printf("\n%d",i);
  ...//a few code here
  printf("\n%d",i);
}
```

Second run i see "i" goes until 200....third run i see "i" goes until 199....and go on...thats the way i checked where it was giving the Segmentation Core (dumped).

**EDIT***

O well im ashamed now, just checked the old Script that was generating the files before the program and it gives the same problem....if i do the generation in a separated file and then only runs the "processFiles()" in the program, it gives the same error. The old Script has an "rm files" command in the end that wasnt concerned about. (thx to user @beta....just checked the old script cause your commentary)

Well....but anyway the question continue, but now i know its not only with the "system" function.

Comment: not without the sources

Comment: Have you used the core to see which line of code seg faulted?

Comment: [Simplify.](http://www.sscce.org) How does the second run change the files? What if you execute `produceSeveralFiles.sh` on the command line, does that cause an error? If not, remove that call from the program and let the program run `processFiles()`, and see if *that* causes the error. Just that much will cut the search space in half.

Comment: I've read your last edit several times; it's *very* unclear, but it sounds as if you've verified that a segfault is occurring in `processFiles()`, in that loop. Fine. Now **simplify** the code until you either spot the bug, or arrive at a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org) you can post.

Comment: --> What if you execute produceSeveralFiles.sh on the command line, does that cause an error? <-- Yes, the error happens here as well, that is what last edit is talking about